# Show context menu of QSystemTrayIcon without user click

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a `QSystemTrayIcon`, that displays a `QMenu` on click, but I want to display the menu as soon as the tray icon is displayed. I have tried calling the `show` method on the `QMenu`, but the menu only seems to display when it is clicked. Any idea on how to change this behaviour?

Comment: I had a similar use case that I answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257052/simulate-user-clicking-in-qsystemtrayicon/23280769#23280769

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to trigger the behaviour triggered by operating system when user clicks the system tray, but at least you should be able to use [QMenu::popup](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#popup) method to just show the menu returned by [QSystemTrayIcon::contextMenu](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html#contextMenu) method.

Note that you should use the menu's size *hint*, when you calculate the menu postion relative to [QSystemTrayIcon::geometry](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html#geometry). Also you may need to use [QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry-3) to make sure the menu pops up inside the screen, no matter where the task bar is.