# Simulate user clicking in QSystemTrayIcon

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, trayicon

Even through the `activated` slot is being executed, the menu is still not showing. I traced through manually clicking the tray icon and the simulated click, and its going through the same execution logic.

Currently I have

```
class MyClass(QObject):
   def __init__():
       self._testSignal.connect(self._test_show)
       self.myTrayIcon.activated.connect(lambda reason: self._update_menu_and_show(reason))

   def show():
       self._testSignal.emit()

   @pyqtSlot()
   def _test_show():
       self._trayIcon.activated.emit(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger)

   @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
   def _update_menu_and_show(reason):
       if reason in (QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger):
        mySystemTrayIcon._update_menu()

...
class MySystemTrayIcon(QSystemTrayIcon):

   def _update_menu(self):
      # logic to populate menu
      self.setContextMenu(menu)
...
MyClass().show()
```

Comment: I just made a quick test on PyQt v4 and it seems to work fine (example is here: http://pastebin.com/NkAQQyqt ). If you can't see anything different about what I did, and/or porting my code to PyQt5 still causes your problem, it might be a bug in PyQt5.

Comment: @three_pineapples your script helped me realize the problem with my setup. Now having an issue with the menu not showing up. Please see edits.

Comment: @mingxiao please remove early part of the question that is no longer relevant since you are technically now looking at a different issue. Keep in mind that SO is not a discussion thread, it is a Q&A forum. The question must be unique and well defined, such that it and the answers are interrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I made the context menu associated with the tray icon pop up

```
class MyClass(QObject):
   def __init__():
       self._testSignal.connect(self._test_show)
       self.myTrayIcon.activated.connect(lambda reason: self._update_menu_and_show(reason))

   def show():
       self._testSignal.emit()

   @pyqtSlot()
   def _test_show():
       self._trayIcon.activated.emit(QSystemTrayIcon.Context)

   @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
   def _update_menu_and_show(reason):
       if reason in (QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger, QSystemTrayIcon.Context):
           mySystemTrayIcon._update_menu()
           # Trigger means user initiated, Context used for simulated
           # if simulated seems like we have to tell the window to explicitly show

           if reason == QSystemTrayIcon.Context:
               mySystemTrayIcon.contextMenu().setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
               pos = mySystemTrayIcon.geometry().bottomLeft()
               mySystemTrayIcon.contextMenu().move(pos)
               mySystemTrayIcon.contextMenu().show()

...
class MySystemTrayIcon(QSystemTrayIcon):

   def _update_menu(self):
      # logic to populate menu
      self.setContextMenu(menu)
...
MyClass().show()
```

It seems you have to set the `WindowStaysOnTopHint` on the context menu so that it will appear.
This solution is specific to mac since it assumes the taskbar is on the top.

One side effect is that the context menu is always on top, even if the user clicks somewhere else. I placed an event filter on the context menu, the only useful event that it registered was `QEvent.Leave`