# PyQt4 to launch system tray icon immediately after login

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I am trying to launch a system tray menu after successful login. I have 2 QtUi screens and the rest is just python code. The login dialog comes first and I want to hide this after login and show the system tray menu. Here is my code so far:

Note: UI_Login is a dialog from QtDesigner

**1. System tray ui**

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):

    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, parent)
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)        
        self.exitAction = menu.addAction("Exit")
        self.helpAction = menu.addAction("Help")
        self.setIcon(icon)
        self.setContextMenu(menu)
```

**2. Login function. Calling SystemTrayIcon**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from modules.ui.login_ui import Ui_Login
from modules.ui.menu_ui import SystemTrayIcon
from api.auth import doLogin

class Login(QtGui.QDialog):
    """
    Login user via the api
    Links the gui and the app functionality
    Logged user token is saved for further processing
    """
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Login()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.doLogin)

    def doLogin(self):
        self.password = unicode(self.ui.password.text())
        self.email = unicode(self.ui.email.text())      
        request_data = {"username": ""+self.email+"", "password": ""+self.password+""}
        response = doLogin(request_data)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            """ 
                1. Save Api token for future entries
                2. Start app. i.e create a system tray app.
            """
            self.token = response.json()['token'];

            self.hide()
            trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Bomb.xpm"))
            trayIcon.show()
            print "End check"
        else:
            #Raise error
            print response.json()
```

**3. Main File**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from modules.login import Login

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = Login()
    login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**PROBLEM**
- System tray icon is not showing up when login dialog close.

Your input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trayIcon` object is a local variable and immediately gets garbage collected once the `doLogin()` method finishes. Storing it as an instance attribute (eg `self.trayIcon`) will stop that and your icon should stay in existence.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day and this gives me insight on how to handle other screens transitions.
Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

`QSystemTrayIcon` has an `activated` signal that you can emit. Connect this signal to some method that will create a `QMenu`.

```
class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        ...
        self.setContextMenu(menu)
        self.activated.connect(lambda reason: self._create_menu)

    def _create_menu(self):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('Quit,None))
        self.setContextMenu(menu)
```

Next you'll want to emit the `activated` signal so that your menu will show. I had a similar use case that's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257052/simulate-user-clicking-in-qsystemtrayicon/23280769#23280769).